# They know vs They knew

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

> They know that we can't break this, that's why they gave it to us.
>   They Knew that we can't break this, that's why they gave it to us.

Which one is correct? I know, knew is past tense of know but I'm confused in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last clause specifies that they *gave it to us in the past*; and they had to *know* in the past, too, that we would be unable to break it, since that is *why* they did so.

However, that knowledge could very easily extend into the present and future, as could our inability to break it.

So either of your examples could be appropriate, depending on context; so could another possibility, with both *KNOW* and *CAN* in past form. Putting time references in should make the differences clearer.

> They **know** *now (and knew at the time when they gave it to us)* that we **can't** break this *now (or at any future time that matters)*; that's why they gave it to us.
>
> They **knew** *when they gave it to us (recently)* that we **can't** break this *now (or at any future time that matters)*; that's why they gave it to us.

OR

> They **knew** *back when they gave it to us* that we **couldn't** break this *at that time (or at any subsequent time that mattered)*; that's why they gave it to us.

Which is correct will depend on what you mean.

Comment: That's doubtless all true - but in practice, if what they *knew* was really "true", it still is, and they can still *know* it. And hardly anyone would actually bother to distinguish the potential nuance of talking about what they *knew* in the past (as opposed to *still* know) unless they had in fact been mistaken. In which case you'd obviously say *"They **thought** we couldn't break it - but of course we **did**"*.